# CSS - мини слайдер/переключатель

Tags: jquery, css

Здравствуйте, помогите нужно сделать слайдер

при нажатие на Next листал вперед при нажатие на Last назад

```
<div class="balalaika">
    <div class="slide"><a href="#"><img src="img/1.jpg" alt=""/></a>
    <a href="#" class="next">Next</a>
    <a href="#" class="last">Last</a>
    <a href="#" class="title">Fnatic</a>
</div>
```

спасибо :)

Comment: походу никто не знает)

Comment: http://yeap.narod.ru/js/022.html

Comment: Скорее, никто не хочет делать работу за автора.  
Что вы уже попытались сами сделать? Что не получилось?